# Adding Payout to User using TextFile

Tags: c#, text-files, .net

I'm having problems adding a payout amount to a user in a text file. Here's my current code:

```
  public string payout = 1;
  public static void AddPayout(int tPayout, string nickx) {
    if (UserIsSub(nickx)) {
        tPayout = payout * 2;
        File.WriteAllLines("loyalty.txt", File.ReadAllLines("loyalty.txt")
            .Select(x => {
                if (x.StartsWith(nickx)) return nickx + " " + tPayout + "\n\r";
                return x;
        }));
    } else {
        tPayout = payout + 1;
        File.WriteAllLines("loyalty.txt", File.ReadAllLines("loyalty.txt")
            .Select(x => {
                if (x.StartsWith(nickx)) return nickx + " " + tPayout + "\n\r";
                return x;
        }));
    }
}
public static bool UserIsSub(String value)
{
    if (File.ReadAllLines("subscribers.txt").Contains(value.ToLower())) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
```

So far it just adds the same person, and keeps the number the same. What can I do the change that?

Comment: I would try reading the file contents completely into memory rather than inlining them in the Linq statements.  You could have an issue reading/writing the same file at the same time.

Comment: I would use `List<string>` since `IEnumerable<string>` would probably still be lazy-loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using the wrong newline code,

try using `\r\n` instead of `\n\r`

(by the way, I dont think you need any newline sign, because writealllines should also write newlines)

then, you should insert a .ToArray after the select, because the file could be still open

then, you are replacing the line of code with the new amount. if you want to add the old one, you need to parse that line and replace the result.

Comment: That fixed it, but I have another problem.. How do I add to their current payment? So if I set `int payment` to 5, they get 6, how do I add to it is my new problem.